# Oracle-SQL Single select, cascade by field

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase what I mean. Let me try: Is there a way to select all elements that cascade by a reference field?

For instance, I have the rows:

```
parentRef   | Reference | Data
------------------------------
aContainer  | mainObj   | "Parent"
mainObj     | secondObj | "Child 1"
secondObj   | thirdObj  | "Child 2"
nonExistent | blankObj  | "Don't select me!"
```

And I want to select mainObj, secondObj, thirdObj in a single statement when I only know one parentRef: "aContainer". Is this possible?

I could do this by having my code perform many queries: `select...where parentRef = 'aContainer'`, then `select...where parentRef = 'mainObj'`, etc, but I really don't want to hammer my DB with many queries, primarily for speed.

Edit: Tree Queries! That's the search term I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle can do Tree Queries, have a look at START WITH and CONNECT BY

Comment: That's what I needed exactly! `start with parentRef = 'aContainer' connect by prior Reference = parentRef`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want something like a correlated query. This will allow you to get only items that have a parent reference in the table.  an example would look something like the following (although I might have reversed the logic):

```
select 
parentRef
, Reference
, Data 
from mytable parentTable 
where Reference in (
select
 reference 
 from mytable childTable 
 where childTable.reference = parenttable.parentref)
```

Comment: Indeed that would work, until I decide to add an item with Reference='nonExistent'. For this example that name doesn't make sense, but it could be anything else. START WITH and CONNECT BY were what I needed exactly, though!